# Upload image exit rename file php

Tags: php

I have problem when I upload one time it OK but if file of image exit it can't more image to the folder it see only message "already upload": let's see my code follow

```
<?php
$name = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        $increment = ''; //start with no suffix

        while (file_exists($name . $increment . '.' . $extension)) {
            $increment++;
        }
        $basename = $name . $increment . '.' . $extension;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $basename);
        echo "already upload";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your echo statement with the "already upload" comment is always going to get hit if your enter that if statement that checks for an existing file.  The file should be uploading though.  You should check the directory where the file is being uploaded to, I bet you will see multiple files there.  You can get rid of the echo, it is misleading where it currently is.

Comment: I have try it again and again but it still not success

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it will resolve your problem :

```
.
.
.
    $increment = ''; //start with no suffix     
    while (file_exists("upload/" .$name . $increment . '.' . $extension)) {
        $increment++;
    }
.......
```

I have tried it. it's now working.